# How to iterate over external input list in pyomo objective function?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, gurobi

I am trying to run a simple LP pyomo Concrete model with `Gurobi`solver :

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

nb_years = 3
nb_mins = 2
step = 8760*1.5
delta = 10000

#Range of hour
model.h = pyo.RangeSet(0,8760*nb_years-1)

#Individual minimums
model.min = pyo.RangeSet(0, nb_mins-1)

model.mins = pyo.Var(model.min, within=model.h, initialize=[i for i in model.min])

def maximal_step_between_mins_constraint_rule(model, min):

    next_min = min + 1 if min < nb_mins-1 else 0
    if next_min == 0: # We need to take circularity into account
        return 8760*nb_years - model.mins[min] + model.mins[next_min] <= step + delta
    return model.mins[next_min] - model.mins[min] <= step + delta

def minimal_step_between_mins_constraint_rule(model, min):

    next_min = min + 1 if min < nb_mins-1 else 0
    if next_min == 0: # We need to take circularity into account
        return 8760*nb_years - model.mins[min] + model.mins[next_min] >= step - delta
    return model.mins[next_min] - model.mins[min] >= step - delta

model.input_list = pyo.Param(model.h, initialize=my_input_list, within=pyo.Reals, mutable=False)

def objective_rule(model):

    return sum([model.input_list[model.mins[min]] for min in model.min])

model.maximal_step_between_mins_constraint= pyo.Constraint(model.min, rule=maximal_step_between_mins_constraint_rule)

model.minimal_step_between_mins_constraint= pyo.Constraint(model.min, rule=minimal_step_between_mins_constraint_rule)

model.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)

opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')
results = opt.solve(model, options={'Presolve':2})
```

Basically I am trying to find two hours in my input list ([which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpz4A.png)) spanning over 3 years of data, with constraints on the distance separating them, and where the sum of both value is minimized by the model.

I implemented my list as a parameter of fixed value, however even if `mutable` is set to `False` running my model produces this error :

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Objective objective with
    index None: RuntimeError: Error retrieving the value of an indexed item
    input_list: index 0 is not a constant value.  This is likely not what you
    meant to do, as if you later change the fixed value of the object this
    lookup will not change.  If you understand the implications of using non-
    constant values, you can get the current value of the object using the
    value() function.
ERROR: Constructing component 'objective' from data=None failed: RuntimeError:
    Error retrieving the value of an indexed item input_list: index 0 is not a
    constant value.  This is likely not what you meant to do, as if you later
    change the fixed value of the object this lookup will not change.  If you
    understand the implications of using non-constant values, you can get the
    current value of the object using the value() function.
```

Any idea why I get this error and how to fix it ?
Obviously, changing the objective function to `sum([pyo.value(model.input_list[model.mins[min]]) for min in model.min])` is not a solution to my problem.
I also tried not to use pyomo parameters (with something like `sum([input_list[model.mins[min]] for min in model.min])`, but pyomo can't iterate over it and raises the following error :

```
ERROR: Constructing component 'objective' from data=None failed: TypeError:
    list indices must be integers or slices, not _GeneralVarData
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple serious syntax and structure problems in your model.  Not all of the elements are included in the code you provide, but you (minimally) need to fix these:

In this snippet, you are initializing the *value* of each variable to a list, which is invalid.  Start with no variable initializations:

```
model.mins = pyo.Var(model.min, within=model.h, initialize=[i for i in model.min])
```

In this summation, you appear to be using a *variable* as the index for some data.  This is an invalid construct.  The value of the variable is **unkown** when the model is built.  You need to reformulate:

```
return sum([model.input_list[model.mins[min]] for min in model.min])
```

My suggestion:  Start with a *very small* chunk of your data and `pprint()` your model and read it carefully for quality *before* you attempt to solve.

```
model.pprint()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @AirSquid. I fix a few issues thanks to `pprint`, yet I still stuggle with my objective function. I get that the variable value is unknown, but given that I know its possible values (within `model.h`), can't I map every possible one to a value in my list of data, which I then minimize ? Is there a way to do that in pyomo ?

Comment: So, I looked a little more closely at what I think you are trying to do.  An optimization model is probably not your best approach.  Why don't you just code a "sliding window" approach that scans your data and keeps track of the best.  It should be very fast even for 100K plus elements.

Comment: You are definitively right. However, I expect to generalize this approach to 20 minimums, and this existence of the delta parameter makes it very hard to solve with a simple script given the large data (170K+ elements)

Comment: I'm not sure what "20 minimums" implies here, but you can make 1 pass over the data, with a delta, and get as many minima as you want, in linear time.  Just scan the "delta window" once, and then as you move things forward by increment of 1 to the lead point and the delta window, just consider the new elements, keep track of what is needed, etc.